# Converting String to Date using dd-MM-yyyy get nil in Xcode 8 in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

if I choose date like `let dateString = "2014-01-12"`, How would I convert string to

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

and then in below format

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

I get nil values in Xcode 8 in Swift 3.0

```
{

let dateString = "2014-01-12"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:"ja_JP")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
print(dateFormatter.date(from:dateString))
}
```

or

```
   let dateString = "2014-01-12"

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    var s = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)! as Date

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

    s = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)! as Date
   print("SecondDate\(s)")
```

In Xcode 7 it works fine.

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat` should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to change date string into `"date string" as Date` then you can change into your particular format. For every format you need to do this first.

You can use the code below.

**Swift 3**

```
extension String {
    func changeDate(_ mydate:String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: mydate)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: convertedDate!)
        return date
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code ,its working for Xcode 8 and in Swift 3.0

Comment: We are changing format here from Date String "yyyy-MM-dd"  to "Your format". @Nirav D

Comment: In case the format for the date formatter is fixed (or, if you don't intend to use this in threaded applications), then you might consider letting the `dateFormatter` be a static property of `String` (or some help class) rather than instantiating a new `DateFormatter` instance at each call to `changeDate(...)`. As a static property, the formatter will be instantiated only once (lazily), on first use.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert to date formate `yyyy-MM-dd` to `dd-MM-yyyy` then your last line should be.

```
let dateString = "2014-01-12"

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
var s = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Get formatted date like this

```
let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: s)
```

Instead of

```
s = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)! as Date
```

You need to just change format of `DateFormatter` and get it as the `String`.

Comment: You got it right from the beginning, but a tip: Instead of **Change this line:** write **Use this line**, much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this**

```
let dateString = "2014-01-12"
        let dateFormatterNew = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterNew.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = dateFormatterNew.date(from: dateString)! as Date

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        let dateNew = dateFormatter.string(from: date )
        print(dateNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
    let datestring = "2014-01-12"
    let dateF = NSDateFormatter()
    dateF.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    let firstDate = dateF.dateFromString(datestring)
    dateF.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    let newDateString = dateF.stringFromDate(firstDate!)

    print("NEW DATE FORMAT IS  : \(newDateString)")
```